# Socket OSError [WinError 10022] when making connect() attempts too quickly

Tags: python, windows, sockets, exception, networking

I have a client that needs to repeatedly poll to see if the expected server is there, and gracefully deal with the fact that it might not be for extended periods of time.

Behold the following test script:

```
import socket, time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(0.1)

delay = 2
connected = False

while not connected:
    try:
        s.connect(("localhost", 50000))    # I'm running my test server locally
        connected = True

    except socket.timeout:
        print("Timed out. Waiting " + str(round(delay, 1)) + "s before next attempt.")
        time.sleep(delay)
        delay -= 0.1
```

The result:

```
Timed out. Waiting 2s before next attempt.
Timed out. Waiting 1.9s before next attempt.
Timed out. Waiting 1.8s before next attempt.
Timed out. Waiting 1.7s before next attempt.
Timed out. Waiting 1.6s before next attempt.
Timed out. Waiting 1.5s before next attempt.
Timed out. Waiting 1.4s before next attempt.
Timed out. Waiting 1.3s before next attempt.
Timed out. Waiting 1.2s before next attempt.
Timed out. Waiting 1.1s before next attempt.
Timed out. Waiting 1.0s before next attempt.
Timed out. Waiting 0.9s before next attempt.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lewis/Desktop/sockettest.py", line 11, in <module>
    s.connect(("localhost", 50000))
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

It appears that if I don't put a delay of about 0.9s between my connect() attempts, I get this exception.

What is going on?

Comment: I think I have seen something like this. It is actually a setting in MS Windows that prevents making many connections in short succession. I can't remember the rationale, but it had to do with protecting others from misbehaving software on your computer. You can configure this through the registry though.

Comment: Interesting, that makes sense. I don't plan on touching this registry setting with my program, and I'm fine with just setting a delay. However, I want to see if I can find some documentation on what the delay might be, as well as any other considerations. I don't like just blindly setting a delay and hoping it works  :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using one socket for every connection "attempt".  A socket can only be used for one connection.  You're actually only making one connection attempt here.  When it finally times out the socket gets to a state where you're not allowed to call `connect` anymore.

Create a new socket for each new connection attempt you want to try.

Comment: Sweet, I can indeed rapidly fire off connect() attempts if I create a new socket every time. I don't follow though how my code is actually only making one connection attempt, nor why there this seemingly arbitrary delay is needed if I'm using the same socket every time.

Comment: Calling `connect` on a socket a second time doesn't attempt a second connection.  That's just how TCP sockets work.

Comment: I modified my client so it tries to connect once, then waits 10s, then tries to connect again, both on the same socket. During the 10s wait, I start the host. The client successfully connects the second time. I still don't follow how it's not attempting a second connection. It sure looks like it is.

Comment: The first connection attempt is still in progress.  The second call to `connect` is just a way to ask the system for the status of that connection attempt.  It will "work" (succeed or timeout) until the connection attempt has succeeded (the connection was accepted) or failed (the connection was rejected or the internal TCP timeout was reached).  Then it simply becomes an error.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. So the connection attempt will only truly be killed when I close the socket, even if it has already timed out, correct?