# How to flood IP addresses to find server

Tags: python, networking, ip, client, server

I am trying to use brute force to generate a range of local ip address in my client with the hope of finding the server's IP which is waiting for a connection.I already know the port number at which the server is listening.Can someone please tell me why my code is not working.Thanks in advance

```
from socket import *
s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
ip="192.168."
print("Searching for IP...")
for i in range(0,256):
    for j in range(0,256):
        host=ip+str(i)+"."+str(j)
        add=(host,1060)
        try:
            s.connect(add)
            print("Server Found:",add)
        except:
            print(host,"failed")
```

Comment: Can I suggest taking a look at scapy http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/ as it provides built in tools for this sort of thing.

Comment: In what way isn't it working? I expect it will just be very slow, since it has to wait for a timeout for all the addresses that aren't in use.

Comment: You may need to create a new socket each time through the loop, I don't know if you can reuse a socket that you tried to connect with already.

Comment: You should also break out of the loops when `s.connect` succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment said, just add something in your code will works:

```
from socket import *

ip="192.168."
print("Searching for IP...")
for i in range(0,256):
    for j in range(0,256):
        host=ip+str(i)+"."+str(j)
        add=(host,1060)
        print host
        s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM) # create the socket in loop
        s.settimeout(4) # set the timeout value as 4 seconds
        try:
            s.connect(add)
            print("Server Found:",add)
        except:
            print(host,"failed")
        s.close() # close it
        del s
```

settimeout will make the code more effective and won't speed too much time.

Use the same socket will be wrong for

```
[Errno 10022]
```

like the code below:

```
from socket import *

ip="192.168."
print("Searching for IP...")
s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM) # create the socket in loop
for i in range(0,256):
    for j in range(0,256):
        host=ip+str(i)+"."+str(j)
        add=(host,1060)
        print host

        #s.settimeout(4) # set the timeout value
        try:
            s.connect(add)
            print("Server Found:",add)
        except Exception, error:
            print(host,"failed")
            print error
        #s.close() # close it
        #del s
```

Comment: This code worked just fine but why do we need to create new socket every time ?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773059/socket-oserror-winerror-10022-when-making-connect-attempts-too-quickly